# How to set the width of R console in terminal evoked from vim?

Tags: r

I installed vim-r-plugin on my Linux computer. The below is the R console prompted by "\rf", but it seems too narrow to show all columns of the data though the terminal window has been wide enough. I am wondering how to make it wider just for the R console.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install that package `setwidth` and put `library(setwidth)` in your `~/.Rprofile`. Then the width of the R console adjusts to the width of your terminal (it will be the same width as the output of `tput cols`).

If you simply want a custom width, you can do `options(width = 120)`, for example.

**Edit:**
The package `setwidth` has been removed from CRAN. Now you can get the desired result with: `options(setWidthOnResize = TRUE)`

Comment: I have done all these settings but there are no change of the width.

Comment: Did you check the changes in the output of `getOption("width")` when you change the width of the window? For the `setwidth` package to work, the output of `system("echo $TERM")` needs to contain `xterm` (for example, my output is `xterm-256color`. If it doesn't, then the window won't resize. You could then put `export TERM='xterm-256color'` in your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` if you use `zsh`) to force this.

Comment: Also, check out section 9.19 [here](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html#r-plugin-use) for more on this issue.

Comment: How to install this package? `install.packages('setwidth')` seems not to work (not found).

Comment: The package was removed from CRAN. Now you can use `options(setWidthOnResize = TRUE)` instead.

Comment: Great solution [here](https://scarff.id.au/blog/2021/updating-r-output-width-after-resizing-the-terminal-startup/).

Answer (score 0):

The `setwidth` package doesn't work as advertised on my configuration (`konsole 20.08.0`, `KDE Plasma 5.19.4`), and it's been removed from CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/setwidth/index.html

Fortunately, it is still available in the archive:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/setwidth/

So, you can install it via:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/setwidth/setwidth_1.0-4.tar.gz")
```

(this is the most recent version, 2015 - not so young)

Now you can execute:

```
library(setwidth)
```

And this sets the `width` option once, to your terminal width.
Check it with:

```
getOption("width")
```

Unfortunately, after resizing nothing happens, despite having `TERM='xterm-256color'` in my environment.

But, putting `library(setwidth)` to my `~/.Rprofile` at least works when I don't resize the terminal. Or, you can save the workspace and restart `R`.